# D3 Clicking a symbol attached to a line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 tree (very similar to this: https://observablehq.com/@mx60s/collapsible-tree) and when I click on a line, it adds a symbol as a child. I'd like to be able to click on the symbol and have it open up a menu, but for some reason I can't get it to respond to a click. I've tried making it sit behind the line so you'd just click on the line again in the same area, but I can't get that to work with z-index or anything.

Here's the relevant code:

```
linkEnter.on('click', d => {

    // Get location of the mouse click
    var x = d3.mouse(d3.event.currentTarget)[0]
    var y = d.target.x

    fault = link
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1)
      .attr('fill', '#555')
      .attr('d', d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCross).size(50))
      .on('click', console.log("Hello!"))
})
```

The .on('click') event doesn't respond - help!

Comment: Instead of directly executing the `console.log()` you need to wrap it in a function whereby creating a callback to be executed once the event is fired: `.on('click', () => console.log("Hello!"))`.

Comment: As a complement to the above comment, your current code executes the function and uses its returned value. The returned value of `console.log` is `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a little mistake. It doesn't work even if it's wrapped in a function.